# Pandas - Returning a boolean if value is in between

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to create a new column named df3['outlier'],  that columnn would contain a boolean, if df3['Rolling_Rate'] is in between df3['LowerControl'] & df3['UpperControl'] return False else True.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `apply`:

```
df3['outlier'] = ~df3['Rolling_Rate'].between(df3['LowerControl'], df3['UpperControl'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
df3['outlier'] = df3.apply(lambda row: True if (row['Rolling_Rate']>=row['LowerControl'] and row['Rolling_Rate']<=row['UpperControl']) else False,axis=1)
```